# How to use MSBuild on multiple applications with different targeted frameworks

Tags: msbuild, target-framework

We have multiple applications using two different targeted frameworks, some are web apps (3.5), and some are winform controls (2.0).

How can we ensure that all the applications are built against their corresponding framework?

Do we have to use the 3.5 version of MSBuild with the 3.5 targeted apps? and MSBuild v2.0 with the 2.0 apps? Will MSBuild auto build against the targeted frameworks unless otherwise instructed?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you ensure you that you are running the highest MSBuild version it should compile all the versions of your Targeted apps. If you are running inside VS then it will take care of compiling this for you. If you are going to directly build all the projects with MSBuild then take a look into

**Multi-targeting Overview**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh264223.aspx and

**MSBuild Target Framework and Target Platform**
      https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh264221.aspx